# Cannot create WSS connection with Chrome, other browser work

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, wss

Almost for two years now Google Chrome does no longer support SSL over websocket.
Now i don't know what really their problem is, other than that i heard they rewrote their WS protocols over SSL.. And sinds i'm using IO::Socket::SSL i wonder if you guys actually know about it. my example site is an irc bot running from a HTTPS host from a javascript connection over WSS. https://lichtsnel.nl.

It did work for years, but since google changed their procedures apparently, and Chrome is the only browser in where it still doesn't work. And i wonder if you guys have noticed this. I've written a client/server library using IO::Socket::SSL for anything SSL related. It works perfectly over HTTPS, but somehow something changes for WSS. And they didn't fixed that.. And that while they probably force the new standaard to HTTPS layers. And without a working WSS layer, chrome becomes really useless.. And i'm forced to fall back to http/ws. With way less functionality left.

Not sure how active these modules are updated, i could update lately, but still nu luck, and if you have any info about their changes in their protocols. So i'm mailing to see if we can expect updates making chrome work again.

With Kind Regards,
OnEhIppY
Domero.

This is the server side code in perl:

```
# SSL
my $sslerr=0;
if ($self->{ssl}) {
  IO::Socket::SSL->start_SSL($client,
    SSL_server => 1,
    SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_PEER,
    SSL_cert_file => $self->{sslcert},
    SSL_key_file => $self->{sslkey},
    SSL_ca_file => $self->{sslca},
    Listen => 128
  ) or $sslerr=1;
  if ($sslerr) { print STDOUT prtm(),"Failed to ssl handshake: $SSL_ERROR\n"; close($client) }
}
```

and the server logs only this:

Failed to ssl handshake: SSL accept attempt failed

Comment: I don't really understand the description of your problem - basically all I understand is that you think Google broke something but the details are unclear for me. Your code fragment also is not sufficient for me to reproduce the problem you have, basically all you provide is a TLS listener which requires (optional) client certificates. It is unclear what client side code is accessing this server. A more clear description of the problem with a way to reproduce it would likely be necessary if you expect useful answers.

Comment: the client side is nothing more than the standaard javascript websocket client, opening on a https host. i could give you my complete server module. to see what the server says and does. but basically my code example is what i only use from the IO::Socket::SSL module to open it. everything works everywhere, except in chrome thus sins they changed something for the wss protocol. and i'm not sure what goes wrong. it seems purely the ssl handshake where it produces only an error message. https does work on the same server module,

Comment: yet websocket itself is broken for chrome based javascript websocket clients.. any other browser or client works over wss. like with firefox you can just connect and chat via the wss connection.. it's completely isolated in chrome only.. so my guess is that chrome changed something. and i have no idea how to fix this part.. so that chrome finally works again..As there are a lot of chrome users complaining they can't open de chat site any longer.. i had to open it for http for them to be able to chat over ws..

Comment: javascript base:

`var wserver = 'wss://chat.lichtsnel.nl:7474';
function connect() {
...
    socket = new WebSocket(wserver);
    socket.onopen = function() {..}
    socket.onmessage = function(evt) {..
etc`

and i have my server module online on : 
https://github.com/FactorialCoin/base/blob/master/perl/site/lib/gserv.pm

Comment: *"yet websocket itself is broken for chrome based javascript websocket clients."* - that is absolutely not true. WSS works in general with Chrome too and is heavily used, including on stackoverflow.com. Just try for example the [tests on websocket.org](https://www.websocket.org/echo.html). Thus it is your specific use case which is not working - but unfortunately you don't provide enough details about this but just claim that WSS in general is broken.

Comment: Is there a debug mode i can set so i can get more info about where and what goes wrong in the handshake routine? As it's that part where things break down.. Or a debug callback so i can trace the loop where it jumps out?

Comment: SSL is notoriously hard to debug because not much information is given on the wire. Chrome just says that it failed and on the server side you will not get more information. But see my answer which might explain what goes wrong and what you can do to fix it.

Comment: on that link you provided it doesn't even connect to the server it seems. my own js gives atleast a handshake error on the server.. and funny enough javascript doesn't even provide error codes .. only the error call.. i truly wish this stuff was better documented.. so far i only have the IO::Socket::SSL call in where chrome doesn't connect right.. and since it's only chrome what does this, i don't know what really has changed.. SSL is only a wrapping layer as far i use it. and my guess is that the IO module itself is where things break down.. i could try to add debug comments though..

Comment: My gserv.pm module is what i use for http/https/ws & wss.. i can also replace apache with it.. although that has something weart as well, as in hanging on calls on some special https client hanging my round robin loop and blocking the whole process from running around.. as it's completely non-blocking based .. it should not block the loop.. but it does on some unique client i don't know who or what that is.

Answer (score 1):

While you don't provide many details and basically claim that WSS is broken with Chrome in general (which is not true) I suspect that the following line from your code is causing the problem:

```
SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_PEER,
```

With this line you request a client certificate. Note that you only request one but don't actually require one, i.e. it is only `SSL_VERIFY_PEER` but not `SSL_VERIFY_PEER|SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT`. This means that the TLS handshake will continue if no client certificate was sent.

Based on [this bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=329884) it looks like Chrome does not prompt the user if a WSS connection requests a client certificate. This means that the connection will fail - unless the necessary client certificate was already requested before for the same origin (i.e. domain+port) and thus the previous choice could be used. Given that you seem to use an origin (domain+port) specific for the WSS connection this is likely not the case - thus it fails.

If you don't need client certificates in the first place (which is likely the case since you treat these as optional) just remove the line which requests one. If you really need client certificates put your Websocket into the same origin as the rest of the site and request the client certificates there. See [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=329884#c40) for a typical way how this is done.

Answer (score 0):

I just had an issue where websockets worked in Firefox but not Chrome. Chrome would connect OK, but then immediately disconnect with a 1006 error code.

Fixed by changing this line:

```
var chatSocket = new WebSocket(wsproto + window.location.host + '/ws/', null, 5000, 10);
```

to this:

```
var chatSocket = new WebSocket(wsproto + window.location.host + '/ws/');
```

The "null" was supposed to be for subprotocols, and I think 5000,10 was left over from a different websocket library used earlier.