# Webpage script connecting to two-way SSL fails

Tags: javascript, python, ssl, websocket

I am running a website server and a websocket server on two different ports. I'd like two-way SSL enabled on both. The website is using a gunicorn/flask app and is working fine for the two-way SSL on all browsers (desktop/mobile, except mobile Firefox). Inside that webpage is a script to connect to the websocket (python websockets server) which also has two-way SSL enabled.
This only works in desktop Firefox; anything else gives the error `WebSocket connection to '<domain>:<port>' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled`.

On desktop Firefox, it requests user certificates for both the webpage and websocket, but like I said anything else returns the above error.

I've been scouring the internet for solutions to this and have seen some info on using proxies with certain hosting providers but I am hosting these myself and would rather not get too deep in setting up further stuff, if possible. For clarification, turning off two-way ssl and only doing server cert verification *does* work. It is only when the websocket asks for the clients cert that nothing happens and the error is in the console (client side, nothing shows on the server side).

Does anyone have ideas on how to keep two-way SSL for the site and websocket? Security is a major concern for this application.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the same problem as described in [Cannot create WSS connection with Chrome, other browser work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62852106/cannot-create-wss-connection-with-chrome-other-browser-work). The problem is that Chrome and Safari will not prompt for a client certificate for a Websockets connection. See [this bug from 2013](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=329884) which is still open.

If the user made already a choice which client certificate to use on the same origin it will work though. Only, an origin includes the port and your Websocket is on a different port than your website. This kind of setup can also cause other problems (like with restrictive firewalls) so it is a good idea to use a single origin and reverse proxy the Websocket from this origin. See [this comment on the same bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=329884#c40) on how to do this with nginx.